# Disable default logging of exceptions

Tags: logging, exception, playframework-2.0

In regards to the Play2 Framework error handling, I catch base exceptions in the `overrided onError` method, in the `Global` class. But I don`t want to log all exceptions that will be caught by this method.

How can I disable exception logging without disabling base logger?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you're trying to solve? (perhaps a small example) Since Play uses Logback, have you looked at [filters](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) or [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html)